# Ionic 2 typescript/angular2 set global variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, global-variables

I am new to Ionic and was wondering if there is a way to dynamically set a global variable and then have it for the rest of the app.

I have an app where on home page I ask user for Phone number and then verify their identity. Once verified I need to store/remember/retrieve for the rest of the app.

Is there a way I can do that rather than passing around it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to save the phone number :

```
 $window.localStorage.setItem("phoneNumber",phoneNumber);
 $window.localStorage.getItem("phoneNumber");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be managing your state in a service (ionic calls them providers, generate one with 'ionic generate provider').

The official tutorial 'Tour of Heroes' covers this. You can find the appropriate section here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html.

basically you create a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{
  public phoneNumber;
}
```

and use it from all your components like this:

```
export class MyComponent{
  constructor(private myService: MyService){}

  setPhone(number: number){
    if(validateNumber(number)){
      this.myService.phoneNumber = number;
    }
  }
}
```